# Discord Bot and Scheduled Tasks

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks, discord.js

I need to my Discord Bot to interact with my server's **channels** and **users** by a **Windows scheduled task**. Basically I need to run a script (task.js) for this scheduled task separated from my main index.js file. My questions are:

1. In this task.js file do I need to create a `new discord.Client()` or can I import the one I've already created in the index.js file? Shall I `client.destroy()` after the task is completed?
2. Do I need to log in my bot again to the client, thorough `client.login('token')`?
3. The channels and users will be ready for use after the event `client.on('ready', () => {}`. So, do I need to put my code inside this event's callback in order to it work properly?

Bonus: In general, when do I really need to do the `client.login('token')`? I'm still confused about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I need to run a script (task.js) for this scheduled task separated from my main index.js file.` Why's that? Why use **Windows scheduled task** ? Why don't you just use any `cron-job` inside `node.js` for separated file?

Answer (score 2):

When you launch this task from the Windows Task Scheduler, you will create another instance of node, separate in memory from your bot that is already running, so you would need to log in again. You'd need to wait for the ready event and tear everything down properly when the task is done. You always need to do client.login before that instance of the Client object can interact with the Discord API on behalf of your bot.

### Possibly a better solution

Use a scheduling library within node on your main instance of the bot. Take a look at [node cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron), for example. This library lets you schedule a function call to occur at any specific time of day, month and even year using a GNU crontab pattern. This lets you use the already logged in instance of your bot, saving a few calls to the Discord API to log your bot in, runs quicker, is cross-platform and less complex.